# FastAPI graphql subscriptions

Tags: fastapi, graphql-subscriptions

I try to implement simple graphql subscription on  FastAPI.

According to documentations but it is not working

```
import asyncio

import graphene
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.graphql import GraphQLApp
from graphql.execution.executors.asyncio import AsyncioExecutor
from starlette.websockets import WebSocket


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    hello = graphene.String(name=graphene.String(default_value="stranger"))

    async def resolve_hello(self,info,name):
        return "Hello " + name

class Subscription(graphene.ObjectType):
    count = graphene.Int(upto=graphene.Int())

    async def subscribe_count(root, info, upto=3):
        for i in range(upto):
            yield i
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

app = FastAPI()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, subscription=Subscription)
app.add_route("/", GraphQLApp(schema=schema, executor_class=AsyncioExecutor))
```

I googled and found that i might need to implement subscription-server like for Sanic or Aiohttp

I try but it doesn't work yet

```
from graphql_ws.websockets_lib import WsLibSubscriptionServer

subscription_server = WsLibSubscriptionServer(schema)

@app.websocket("/subscriptions")
async def subscriptions(websocket: WebSocket):
    await subscription_server.handle(websocket)
    return websocket
```

Error recieve:

```
 return self.ws.open is False
AttributeError: 'WebSocket' object has no attribute 'open'
```

What i'm doing wrong and how it could be solved? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out

below is workable solution

```
import asyncio

import graphene
import pydantic
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette_graphene3 import GraphQLApp, make_playground_handler
from graphene_pydantic import PydanticObjectType


class Subscription(graphene.ObjectType):
    count = graphene.String()

    async def subscribe_count(root, info):
        for i in range(300):
            yield f"{i}"
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, subscription=Subscription)


app.mount("/", GraphQLApp(schema, on_get=make_playground_handler()))
```